# Javascript: how to wait for result of one fetch then start another

Tags: javascript, json, fetch, es6-promise

This code is definitely wrong, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

E.g.

```
fetch('api/foo?get_max=True')
    .then( function(response) {
        return response.json();
    }
    .then( function(response) {
        var max = response["max"];
    }

fetch('api2/bar?max=' + max)
    .then( function(response) {
        return response.json();
    }
    .then( function(mydata) {
        processdata(mydata);
    }
```

This obviously doesn't work, because the max var that will eventually be defined in the first fetch does not yet exist when the second fetch runs.  How can I "chain" or force the second fetch to "wait" for the first fetch?

Comment: put the second fetch where you have `var max =`

Comment: I have tried putting the second fetch within a third then block of the first fetch without success.  I haven't tried putting it directly in the second then block.

Comment: as your second block doesn't return anything, it's no surprise a third block fails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `fetch()` returns a promise you can return it from a `then()` and it will behave as expected:

```
fetch('api/foo?get_max=True')
.then( response => response.json())
.then( response => {
    var max = response["max"];
    return fetch('api2/bar?max=' + max)
})
.then( response => response.json())
.then( mydata => processdata(mydata))
```

Comment: second `.then` is simply `.then(response => fetch('api2/bar?max=' + response.max))`

Comment: I had tried this before and didn't have success, but it's very probable I simply fat fingered something.  Will try again shortly.

Comment: @JaromandaX agreed that's nicer.

Comment: @senorsmile one mistake that's easy to make is forgetting the `return`

Comment: I just tested and confirmed that I wasn't returning anything.  That was preventing the chain from working.  Thanks!